# calculating pixel size from ppi

Tags: css, ppi

I need some help to verify that i have made my calculations correct.

I want to determine number of pixels in the span of 13.6 millimeters for a specific device that is 224,17 pixels per inch.

( if 1 inch = 224.17ppi therefor: 1 centimeter = 569.39ppcm therefor: 1 millimeter = 5.69 ppmm )

**I calculate 13.6mm = 77.35 pixels**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(224.17 pixels / 1 inch) * (1 inch / 25.4 mm) * 13.6 mm = **120 pixels**

Comment: centimeters are smaller than inches; that's one obvious place where your initial math is off.

Answer (score 0):

you can user converter for your ease like

http://endmemo.com/sconvert/millimeterpixel.php